# Convert apache htaccess to nginx RewriteEngine

Tags: nginx

```
RewriteRule ^playlist/(.+)\.txt$ video.php?action=playlist&file=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9]{32})/([a-zA-Z0-9/\+=]+)/([0-9]{1})\.(flv|mp4)$ video.php?url=$2&base64=1&action=play&sec_hash=$1&quality=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/\+=]+)/([0-9]{1})\.(flv|mp4)$ video.php?url=$1&base64=1&action=play&quality=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^download/([a-z0-9]{32})/([a-zA-Z0-9/\+=]+)\.(flv|mp4)$ video.php?url=$2&base64=1&action=download&sec_hash=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^download/([a-zA-Z0-9/\+=]+)\.(flv|mp4)$ video.php?url=$1&base64=1&action=download [L]
```

i try this cod but dont working

## nginx configuration

```
location /playlist { rewrite ^/playlist/(.+)\.txt$ /video.php?action=playlist&file=$1 break; }
location / { rewrite "^/([a-z0-9]{32})/([a-zA-Z0-9/\+=]+)/([0-9]{1})\.(flv|mp4)$" /video.php?url=$2&base64=1&action=play&sec_hash=$1&quality=$3 break; }
location / { rewrite "^/([a-zA-Z0-9/\+=]+)/([0-9]{1})\.(flv|mp4)$" /video.php?url=$1&base64=1&action=play&quality=$2 break; }
location / { rewrite "^/download/([a-z0-9]{32})/([a-zA-Z0-9/\+=]+)\.(flv|mp4)$" /video.php?url=$2&base64=1&action=download&sec_hash=$1 break; }
location /download { rewrite ^/download/([a-zA-Z0-9/\+=]+)\.(flv|mp4)$ /video.php?url=$1&base64=1&action=download break; }
location / { rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9/\+=]+)\.jpg$ /video.php?url=$1&base64=1&action=thumb break; }
```

Comment: Dear, show us the code that you've already tested.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location / { 
    rewrite ^/playlist/(.+)\.txt$ /video.php?action=playlist&file=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/([a-z0-9]{32})/([a-zA-Z0-9/\+=]+)/([0-9]{1})\.(flv|mp4)$ /video.php?url=$2&base64=1&action=play&sec_hash=$1&quality=$3 last;
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9/\+=]+)/([0-9]{1})\.(flv|mp4)$" /video.php?url=$1&base64=1&action=play&quality=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/download/([a-z0-9]{32})/([a-zA-Z0-9/\+=]+)\.(flv|mp4)$ /video.php?url=$2&base64=1&action=download&sec_hash=$1 last;
    rewrite ^/download/([a-zA-Z0-9/\+=]+)\.(flv|mp4)$ /video.php?url=$1&base64=1&action=download last;
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9/\+=]+)\.jpg$ /video.php?url=$1&base64=1&action=thumb last;
}
```